# A div is bigger than what I made it

Tags: javascript, html, css, conways-game-of-life

I am making a John Conway's game of life and when I try run it by pressing space, it is actually bigger than what the console shows it to be. I set the div to be exactly 0.1% of the bigger grid which is in dark blue. But it seems to just be bigger or smaller. I also use panning and zooming for the project

```js
//Important variable
var mainGrid = document.querySelector(".main-grid")

var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight

var time = 500
var Data = {
    livingCells: [
        [3,0],
        [5,0],
        [4,1],
        [5,1]
    ]
}










//functions
var updateCells = (rle) => {
    if (!rle) {
        $(".main-grid").empty()
        
        for (let i = 0; i < Data.livingCells.length; i++) {
            const element = Data.livingCells[i];
            
            
            $(".main-grid").append('<div id="'+i+'" class="on"></div>')
            $('#'+i+'').css({ 'left': element[0]/10+'%', 'top': element[1]/10+'%' ,})
            console.log(element[1])
        }
    }
    
}



var ID;

var cellInterval = () => {
    
    ID = setInterval(() => {



        updateCells()
    }, time)

}





var intervalOn = false;

//listeners
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.key == " " ||
        e.code == "Space" ||      
        e.keyCode == 32      
    ) {
        if(!intervalOn){
            cellInterval()
            intervalOn = true;
            console.log("interval on")
        } else {
            clearInterval(ID)
            intervalOn = false;
            console.log("interval off")

        }
    
        
    }
}




// panzoom
panzoom(mainGrid, {
    minZoom: 0.3,
    maxZoom: 10,
    initialZoom: 1.5,
    initialX: mainGrid.offsetWidth/2,
    initialY: mainGrid.offsetWidth,
    bounds: true,
    boundsPadding: 0.3

});
```

```css
   * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gray;
}
.main-grid{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vw;  
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

   
}



.hover:hover{
    transition: 0.3s;
    background-color: rgb(79, 124, 182);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.on{
    position: fixed;
    height: 0.1%;
    width: 0.1%;
    background-color: white;
    
    
}
```

```html
 <body>
        <div class="main-grid">     
        </div>   
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src='https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js'></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: There seems to be Javascript code missing from your question.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I just added the javascript code. Thanks about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Include

- {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

Comment: I tried using box-sizing: border-box but it did not help. It is still bigger than what the console shows it